# Непонятный баг с поеданием ресурсов видеоплеером на openframeworks

Tags: c++

В общем написал видеоплеер на фреймворке
**https://github.com/jvcleave/ofxOMXPlayer**

который основывается на
**http://openframeworks.cc/**

Итог: **OpenGL + Texture + FFMPEG\Gstreamer**
Проблема в том, что когда я руками в консоли приложение запускаю, оно ест в среднем 36% CPU

Но если я поставлю это приложение на автозапуск например в кроне

```
#@reboot /home/pi/openFrameworks/..
```

или в автозагрузке какого нибудь DE, то тоже самое приложение начинает есть 96% CPU

Т.е. приложение ест 96% при любом автоматическом способе запуска оного.
Пробовал ставить задержку **sleep 30**, не помогло.

М.б. есть идеи у кого?

Comment: - воспроизводиться ли видео так же хорошо или заметны тормоза?
- как измеряете загрузку процессора?
- у Вас 4ядерный процессор?

Comment: RPi  1x700 Mhz  
видео замедляется при смене файла, а потом плавно "разгоняется",  
но постоянно ест все 99% CPU  
если же бинарник запускать руками, то всё работает нормально, загрузка CPU ~30-40%  
замеряю командой top  
FPS видео замеряю на C++ самим плеером

Comment: Ага, это малинка. Скорее всего при старте ручками работает аппаратное ускорение, а вот при запуске с автозагрузки работает программное ускорение. Этим легко объяснить нагрузку процессора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему с помощью данного способа:

Открываем:

```
sudo nano /etc/inittab
```

Комментируем строку терминала tty1 ("1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 115200 tty1"), и добавляем за ней строку:

```
1:2345:respawn:/bin/login -f pi tty1 /dev/tty1 2>&1
```

Теперь pi юзер будет автоматически логиниться.

Переходим в /home/pi/

Создаём файл startup.sh

```
touch startup.sh
chmod a+x startup.sh
```

Прописываем его в конце .bashrc :

```
~/startup.sh
```

И прописываем в файле startup.sh всё, что должно автоматически стартануть.

При данном способе загрузка процессора корректная.